# webclient().downloadstring won't load everything

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, webclient

Hello I am using visual basic class webclient to download an html document into a string.

Here is the code

```
 Dim htmlsource As String
    htmlsource = New System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString("website")
    RichTextBox1.Text = htmlsource
```

The problem is that (webclient().downloadstring) only downloads a part of the website loads as the rest of the html document loads a few seconds after the webpage is loaded. Is there a work around this? Like putting a delay or similar

Comment: Sorry, I am trying to understand your explanation of the problem in that last sentence, and I can't understand it.  Can you re-read the sentence and see if perhaps you can clarify it please?

Comment: Most likely the web site is using Javascript and Ajax to build the page.

When you download the website as a string, you don't get any of that stuff.

Comment: Yes exactly the webpage uses some kind of javascript, probably ajax to load a section.

Comment: I am just thinking - get the page loaded into browser control and save it from there, no?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
WebClient Client = new WebClient();
string tempHtml = Client.Encoding.GetString(Client.DownloadData(IncomingAddress));

dim Client as new WebClient()
dim tempHtml as String = Client.Encoding.GetString(Client.DownloadData(IncomingAddress))
```

your problem is very familiar with all internet spiders, your content come from ajax, you cannot see it because it load in a different request, for doing this is you need to work through browser or webkit...

Comment: you can try it, but i think the problem is the ajax calls, you can use webkit for .Net http://webkitdotnet.sourceforge.net, with this you can see all the calls and the traffic...

Comment: I will try it but Sorry that i'm a bit unfamiliar with c  but could you tranlsate that code into vb.net?

Comment: you can easy translate between the languages using this site http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/

Comment: thanks! Only problem is that there is an error stating that the Webclient() is not defined. I assume that you mean a website?

Comment: add this to the top of the file: Imports System.Net

Comment: unfortunately it didn't work, but I really appriciated your help, thanks! I will try webkit. Browser is not an option as the IE caches sites and that prevents new html data!